# Use utf-8 character for QComboBox::down-arrow {image}

Tags: qt, qt5, stylesheet, pyqt5

I would like to make changing the color theme for my gui as easy as possible. As such I would like to use the ▼ as the drop-down arrow image which is then painted in the color defined by `color`.

So in summery I'm looking for something like this:

```
QComboBox::down-arrow {
   image: ▼;
}
```

Is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

Qt doesn't implement that. You could patch Qt to implement it, though.